# upload image to the server using https webservice

Tags: android, https

How can I upload image to the server using https webservice I know how to accomplish this using http  webservices do I need to do something different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https encryption is transparently handled by the web server and your browser/application so you do not need to do anything else. Just accomplish it in the same way as you were doing with http url.